# Iterator assignment expression inside vector inizialization not working

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I have a vector of byte and want to parse it to members in my struct. I do that by incrementing the iterator until i reach the end. I wanted to avoid calling the std::next twice like here:

```
using RawData = std::vector<std::byte>;
auto iter = message.begin();
auto rawSequenceNumber = RawData{iter, std::next(iter, sizeof(int))};
iter = std::next(iter, sizeof(int));
```

and instead wanted to put the assignment in an expression. But this way the vector rawSequenceNumber stays empty. Why doesn't this code work:

```
using RawData = std::vector<std::byte>;
auto iter = message.begin();
auto rawSequenceNumber = RawData{iter, (iter = std::next(iter, sizeof(int)))};
```

Comment: I guess that's UB because order of evaluation of function's arguments is unspecified https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order

Comment: I think you are right.

Comment: I think it's not _undefined_ but _unspecified_ behaviour. But basically it has the same implication, you can't do it that way.

Comment: Can you explain the difference? For me undefined means everything can happen but that's also possible if it is unspecified (in the standard) or does unspecified means the compiler programmer can choose what happens but it has always to happen the same? Or in other words the compiler programmer specify if the behaviour is unspecified? If it is undefined no one does?

Comment: unspecified: a few different things can happen, and any of them can happen every time. implementation-defined: compiler says what will happen, and it will happen every time. UB: *anything* can happen.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I think this is well defined from c++17.